# First matching ancestor depeding on name

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Hello XPath/Xslt Friends,

i have the following Xml. I want to determine the id of the first matching section or chapter of my `cout` element. If the the closest node of the `cout` is a chapter, then i will get the chapter id, otherwise the section id.

```
<book>
    <chapter id="chapter1">
        <aa>
            <cout></cout> --> i will get "chapter1"
        </aa>
        <section id="section1">
            <a>
                <b>
                    <cout></cout> --> i will get section1
                </b>
            </a>
        </section>
        <section id="section2">
            <a>
                <b>
                    <cout></cout> --> i will get section2
                </b>
            </a>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

i tried the following statement:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[local-name() = 'section' or local-name() = 'chapter']/@id" />
```

but in case of the `cout` contained in section1, it will give me chapter1, instead of section1. Any solutions?

Comment: Can there be any other ancestor elements than `section` or `chapter` having an `id` attribute? If not you can simply use `(ancestor::*/@id)[last()]`. Or of course you can use `(ancestor::*[self::section or self::chapter]/@id)[last()]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your current statement is selecting all ancestors with the name `section` or `chapter`, and after being selected, `xsl:value-of` will only return the value of the first one, in document order (in XSLT 1.0 that is).

Try this instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*[local-name() = 'section' or local-name() = 'chapter'][1]/@id" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. My solution was close, but i didn´t notice my fault :D.

Answer (score 0):

if `cout` has no ancestor `section` , print `chapter` id
else print `section` id.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//cout">
          <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::section)= 0">
               <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter/@id"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::section)>0">
              <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::section/@id"/>
          </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```